Placement of a temp layer
Updated to 3.34.4-Prizren and when creating a temp layer like "Union" or "SinglePart(?)" it used to be placed in the direkt spot over the layer that was active in the layerpanel(?) but now it is placed in the top spot making it much harder to keep track of which is the one you want to use
a) Is the placement something that you can change?
b) For a couple of years ago I asked if there was a way to autoname temp-layers like how it worked ArcGis since the 90s, like Union1, Union2, Union3.... is it a feature in this new version?
